# How to dynamically parse request body in go fiber?

Tags: go, go-fiber

I have an API built in go fiber.
I'm tryng to parse request body data as key value pairs dynamically.

As we know, fiber has `context.Body()` and `context.Bodyparser()` methods to do this but I couldn't find any proper example to do this dynamically with these methods.

e.g:

```golang
func handler(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    req := c.Body()
    fmt.Println(string(req))
    
    return nil
}
```

output:

```
key=value&key2=value2&key3&value3
```

What I'm looking for is a dynamic json like:

```json
{
    key:"value",
    key2:"value2",
    key3:"value3",
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content's [mime-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not `application/json`. To parse that you can use [`net/url.ParseQuery`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url@go1.17.8#ParseQuery). The result of that is a `map[string][]string` which you can then easily convert to a `map[string]string` and then marshal that with the [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.17.8) package to get your desired JSON output.

Here's a code you can start with:

```golang
func handler(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    values, err := url.ParseQuery(string(c.Body()))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    obj := map[string]string{}
    for k, v := range values {
        if len(v) > 0 {
            obj[k] = v[0]
        }
    }

    out, err := json.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    fmt.Println(string(out))
    return nil
}
```